# Order of calling "then" and "success" in jQuery deferred objects

Tags: jquery, deferred

I am loading some data through a `$.get` method. I have used the a success function in the `get` call. But I'm also using a `when`/`then` construction.

Do both callbacks get called, and if so, which occurs first and why?

```
$.when(
  $.get("test.html", functionA )
).then( functionB );
```

If successful, is this guaranteed to call `functionA`, then `functionB`? Or is there a situation where B might occur before A, or can something in `functionA` ever prevent `functionB` from being called? I couldn't find the answer in the jQuery docs.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks - interesting... "execute simultaneously" - are you saying they will be called on different threads? I find that surprising because most JS seems to be run sequentially, but i suppose anything is possible in today's browsers!

Comment: Sorry, my bad, they're executed in sequence: https://jsfiddle.net/wm1t4zrh/

Comment: The only correct answer here is to stop using both.  Pick one technique or the other.  My strong preference is for promises because they are so much more capable in other ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Summary:** The `functionA` will be called earlier, than the `functionB` in your example.  The `success` and `error` callbacks from `jQuery.ajax` settings (or passed to `$.get` in your example) will be called earlier, than any callback attached to the returned `jqxhr` object later.  Well, *today* :-)

**Details:** Documentation of [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) does not mention this.  You'd better avoid depending on it, if you can.

As long as you develop with a particular jQuery version, you can inspect its implementation and assume, that it doesn't change. If you upgrade, you should check, if the assumption is still valid.

For example, latest releases in all supported branches of jQuery (1.12.4, 2.2.4 and 3.1.1) register the `success` and `error` callbacks from jQuery.ajax settings *before the caller gets the `jqxhr` object and can register their callbacks*.  The `jqxhr` object is a [Deferred Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) which guarantees, that handlers attached to its resolution or rejection are executed in the order of their attaching.  You can confirm it in the documentation of [deferred.done()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/), for example.  It means, that, `success` and `error` callbacks from jQuery.ajax settings will be always called earlier, than any callback attached to the returned `jqxhr` object later.

See [jQuery.ajax 3.1.1 sources](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.1.1/src/ajax.js#L662):

```
// Install callbacks on deferreds
completeDeferred.add( s.complete );
jqXHR.done( s.success );
jqXHR.fail( s.error );
```

I admit, that changing the order of execution is rather unlikely in future jQuery updates.  That's why I think, that depending on it would be pretty stable.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! For now,I think I'll risk it being stable.